# When do you have to link Frameworks and Libraries to an XCode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, frameworks

Background: I started a test `Swift` project to understand and expand my knowledge on how to implement `CoreData` into my projects. And of course whenever I'm just testing and playing around with code, I always get sidetracked and seem to get stuck on some tangential topic. This one now being when is it necessary that you directly link a Framework or Library to an XCode project.

So how this came up... I'm creating subclasses of `NSManagedObject` for which I have to (write) `import CoreData` in my `Swift` file. And everything seems to be working perfect; no errors, warnings, etc. However when I check which frameworks and libraries are linked to my project in my "project and targets listing" none are listed. I then realize same goes for when you have to `import UIKit`. Obviously there's the option to directly link these frameworks but it doesn't seem it is necessary to do so.

So as for my question, are there default frameworks that don't have to be explicitly linked to XCode projects, or will I have to eventually link these frameworks when I package up my project for deployment? And if this is not the case, from a broader standpoint, when is it necessary to explicitly link Frameworks and Libraries to an XCode project?

Edit***

If all Apple frameworks are already automatically linked.... Then what is the point of having them available to add to your project. (Mind you, `CoreData.framework` wasn't originally linked explicitly like it is in the picture.)

[image: Project Settings]

Comment: All apple frameworks are automatically linked, and you just need say 'import   <framework>  in your sources to use them. Any other third party you need to explicitly link and embed into your project.

Comment: So then what's the point of having them available to explicitly link to in your project settings?

Comment: the frameworks are part of the iPhone environment, but there are a lot of them and a majority will not be directly needed by your project. for each library you explicitly say you're going to use, the library has to be loaded and interpreted which uses up some system resources

Answer (score 31):

There is no magic happening.
 This is because of module and auto-linking introduced by Xcode(LLVM).
(related keywords : **@import rather than #import** and build-setting options like **Enable Modules, Link frameworks automatically**, by default, set to YES both).
[image]

Automatically, these two keyword(module, auto-linking flag options) combinations try to find and add any related all frameworks that support modules.
As introduced from Xcode 5(actually, LLVM and clang compiler front-end), Internally, the LLVM with above default projects setting has been to use the module system to automatically link any frameworks in code through @import/#import statements.

Once the frameworks are automatically linked with that, developers don't need to put them in Linked Frameworks & Libraries anymore.

So, That's why Apple system frameworks(default frameworks) do not have to be explicitly linked to Xcode projects.

Since the module was available in Xcode, there is no need to continue to import all system frameworks list in .pch file(precompiled prefix header.)
So, that's why also pch setup is set to NO and no needed by default behind the scene.

The limitation, as far as I know so far, is these are only available for Apple system frameworks until now, meaning it cannot be applied to user frameworks and other C/C++ libraries.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Helpful to know. Thanks.